# How can I remove "\n" from scraped data in python?

Tags: python, scrapy

There is a text file about scraped data in this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iu_rJUb-3EROWbctugdlUp9w0JNeiTvY/view?usp=sharing

I want to remove `\n` and `\t` characters from scraped data with Scrapy.

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = TutorialItem()
    sel = Selector(response)
    item['url'] = response.url[0].strip()
    item['title'] = response.meta['link_text']

    # extracting basic body

    item['body'] = w3lib.html.remove_tags(w3lib.html.remove_tags_with_content(sel.xpath('//body').extract()[0].replace("\r\n", " "),which_ones=('script',)))


    with open('abc.txt', 'a') as f:
      f.write('body: {0}\n'.format(item['body']))

    return item
```

In above code, I removed some `\r\n` characters but not all.

```
item['body'] = w3lib.html.remove_tags(w3lib.html.remove_tags_with_content(sel.xpath('//body').extract()[0].replace("\r\n", " "), which_ones=('script',)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing them separately:

EX:

```
item['body'] = w3lib.html.remove_tags(w3lib.html.remove_tags_with_content(sel.xpath('//body').extract()[0].replace("\n", " ").replace("\r", ""),which_ones=('script',)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I have an another question,there is some code fragments such as                                                                              
"@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) { #mobile_top { display: none; } } ".How can I remove these?

Comment: why not use the same replace method method ?replace( "@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) { #mobile_top { display: none; } } ", "")

Comment: I tried this but it did not.This code fragment is still appearing.

Comment: Content is in this link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/17EQNqJGkN5Had0lShxd0WVicylaO4hP4/view?usp=sharing